# variables in img src

Tags: php

this is going to an easy one i think but for the life of me i cant get it to work.

i have a variables $id i want to put it in a img src that i have echo (eg. "uploaded/$id.jpg")

i have tried lots of way and looked all over the net and cant get it to work

```
echo "

            <td>
             <img src="uploaded'.$id'.jpg">
            </td>

 ";
```

this is what the echo looks like if anyone can tell me why it is not work would be a big help

Comment: You should switch to an editor that has syntax highlighting...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because you're mixing your double quotes with single quotes and you forgot the `.` concat operator after `$id`. Try this:

```
echo '

        <td>
         <img src="uploaded/'.$id.'.jpg">
        </td>

';
```

Answer (score 3):

No one stated the obvious:

**Separate HTML and PHP, don't echo HTML**:

```
<td>
    <img src="uploaded/<?php echo $id; ?>.jpg">
</td>
```

Comment: for this, you get an upvote. I always code it echoing PHP into HTML, not echoing HTML from PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing single and double quotes.  Try this:

```
echo "<td>
<img src='uploaded/{$id}.jpg' />
</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using double quotes inside a double quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "<td>
 <img src='uploaded{$id}.jpg'>
 </td>
 ";
```

Your mixing of quote styles is the problem. This should work.

or

```
echo "<td>
<img src=\"uploaded{$id}.jpg\">
</td>
";
```

if you're worried about valid html... 100 ways to skin a cat.

Comment: thanks that works but when the pages come's up the {} are still there so the img dose not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "<td>
    <img src=\"uploaded/{$id}.jpg\">
</td>";
```

EDIT: I think you were missing a / in the image path. Is "uploaded" a directory?

You were mixing single and double quotes. Double quotes allow you to embed variable in them like this... "Hello, $name" but if you tried "name$firstBlue", PHP would assume you were trying to insert the value of $firstBlue. You'd have to use "name{$first}Blue" for that to work. Always placing variables in {curly braces} is a good habit, because it prevents silly mistakes.

Comment: Haha just saw that. SORRY DUDE! ;)

Comment: I second guessed myself when I wrote that after seeing 2,200 rep :P

Answer (score 0):

why it is not working.

```
 echo "//double quotes begins here

                <td>
                 <img src="/*it will end here later portion will not be printed*/ uploaded'.$id'.jpg">
                </td>
 ";
```

you can use

```
echo '<td>
         <img src="uploaded/'.$id.'.jpg">
        </td>
';
```